# "Word addin doesn't work on word online" - For Word online, is it possible to insert xmlfiles - that have contentControls included into footer?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

Related to my earlier question - "Word addin doesn't work on word online".
Seems that there is not so easy to put contentControls in either header or footer. Have tried with worddocuments with Everything in it - header content and footer content allready included, and with contentControls in both. Now the documents only include 1 contentControler just under header. Then in the code I insert header and footer content as ooxml - insertOoxml - you can see it in the code in the earlier question.

EDIT: The new [footer.xml](https://mdproduktion.se/codeandstuff/footer.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, our rich API (insertOoxml) can be used to insert content control into header/footer.

And the precondition is that the ooxml string should have the information about the content control.

For example, we can use the GetOoxml to get the ooxml string which contains the content control.

Comment: Ok - Yes it works in a way now with the header and footer. The header isn't a problem at all dough I Think you can strip the xml-file further.   The footer is cleaned from tabs and stuff so that isn't a problem either. My scenario is like this now. Open up a new document in Word online, open upp addin, getting a blank document, choosing doc from dropdown. Then a long procedure starts with multiple loadings. first the doc, then header and footer. Problem is that only the contentControl in body shows up as input textfield. When you choose Another doc it starts the loading procedure again

Comment: After a long loading proc. you now get the inputfields, but the body contentControl isnt updated - well if you klick on it it Changes, but then it gets all wierd. If you klick bellow it dissapears and you can't input anything in doc-body. Yo have a simillar procedure when you put something in the inputfields an klick submit. YOu get the input but you can't se it right away.

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro the problem you said above. But, I think this might be caused by the running order of your script code. We suggest you to include just one operation in one batch and use 'return context.sync().then()' to concatenate different batches.

Comment: With respect to the long loading time, the actual time is based on the file size and network state. We suggest you to load all the contents in one calling and reduce the calling times.

Comment: Thanks @Jiajia I will try to do that. Still wonder if you can strip down the footer.xml further than it is now.